# How can I find the top X most expensive EC2 instances (including EBS) in my VPC with boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I'm aware of all the separate methods of getting the instances and the volumes and the pricing.

But is there any other way than pulling all that information down and putting it all together?

There are a lot of instances in the VPC and even more EBS volumes. I'm trying to bake this all into a web app, so the overhead on making all the calls is quite substantial.

I can work around it in certain aspects, filtering out via certain instance types and volume sizes. But I was hoping there was a more elegant solution, or at least someone has spent some time on this before and can give guidance?

I'm only really interested in the price per hour of the instance, I'm not worried about historical, just what it's costing right now.

Comment: No, there is no alternative to listing the instances, calling the pricing API and calculating the costs. Some third-parties provide apps that do all this work for you, and simply present a simplified breakdown of the costs but they charge for this service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've hacked this together from several other resources, seems to be working well for me.

You need to change the vpc_ids if you want to run it yourself, or just take the relevant functions.

The lru_cache is in there to reduce the lookups to aws. Still takes a while to run, though not as long as the https://github.com/lyft/awspricing library that I also tried.

```
import json
import boto3

from pkg_resources import resource_filename
from functools import lru_cache


region = "us-east-1"
vpc_ids = ["YOURVPCID"]

ec2 = boto3.resource("ec2", region)
ec2_client = boto3.client("ec2", region)
price_client = boto3.client("pricing", region)


def get_price_from_pricelist(response):
    for result in response['PriceList']:
        json_result = json.loads(result)
        for json_result_level_1 in json_result['terms']['OnDemand'].values():
            for json_result_level_2 in json_result_level_1['priceDimensions'].values():
                for price_value in json_result_level_2['pricePerUnit'].values():
                    continue
    return float(price_value)


# Translate region code to region name
@lru_cache
def get_region_name(region_code):
    default_region = "EU (Ireland)"
    endpoint_file = resource_filename("botocore", "data/endpoints.json")
    try:
        with open(endpoint_file, "r") as f:
            data = json.load(f)
        return data["partitions"][0]["regions"][region_code]["description"]
    except IOError:
        return default_region


@lru_cache
def get_ec2_price(instance_type, os="Linux", region=region):
    # Search product filter
    resolved_region = get_region_name(region)
    filter = [
        {'Field': 'tenancy',         'Value': 'shared',              'Type': 'TERM_MATCH'},
        {'Field': 'operatingSystem', 'Value': os,                    'Type': 'TERM_MATCH'},
        {'Field': 'preInstalledSw',  'Value': 'NA',                  'Type': 'TERM_MATCH'},
        {'Field': 'instanceType',    'Value': instance_type,         'Type': 'TERM_MATCH'},
        {'Field': 'location',        'Value': resolved_region,       'Type': 'TERM_MATCH'},
        {'Field': 'capacitystatus',  'Value': 'Used',                'Type': 'TERM_MATCH'},
        {'Field': 'storage',         'Value': 'EBS only',            'Type': 'TERM_MATCH'},
        {'Field': 'marketoption',    'Value': 'OnDemand',            'Type': 'TERM_MATCH'},
        {'Field': 'licenseModel',    'Value': 'No License required', 'Type': 'TERM_MATCH'},
    ]

    response = price_client.get_products(ServiceCode="AmazonEC2", Filters=filter)
    return get_price_from_pricelist(response)


@lru_cache
def get_ebs_price(ebs_code, region=region):
    if ebs_code == 'standard':
        return 0.05 # Just hard code this, it doesn't fit the search and is rarely used

    resolved_region = get_region_name(region)
    filter = [
        {'Type': 'TERM_MATCH', 'Field': 'usagetype', 'Value': f"EBS:VolumeUsage.{ebs_code}"}, 
        {'Type': 'TERM_MATCH', 'Field': 'location',  'Value': resolved_region}
    ]
    response = price_client.get_products(ServiceCode='AmazonEC2', Filters=filter)
    return get_price_from_pricelist(response)


def get_instance_price(id):
    instance = ec2.Instance(id)
    volumes = instance.volumes.all()
    vols = [(x.volume_type, int(x.size)) for x in volumes]
    instance_type = instance.instance_type
    ec2_monthly = get_ec2_price(instance_type) * 30 * 24
    total_monthly = 0 + ec2_monthly
    for vol in vols:
        vols_monthly = get_ebs_price(vol[0]) * vol[1]
    total_monthly += vols_monthly
        # print(f"{vol} - Month: ${month:.2f} Hour: ${month / (30 * 24):.2f}" )
    print(f"{total_monthly:.2f}:{id}:{vols}:{vols_monthly}:{instance_type}:{ec2_monthly}", flush=True)
    return total_monthly


def main():
    req = ec2_client.describe_instances(Filters=[{"Name": "vpc-id", "Values": vpc_ids}])

    for reservation in req["Reservations"]:
        for instance in reservation["Instances"]:
            id = instance["InstanceId"]
            get_instance_price(id)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```